# Why wouldn't Hank or Gomez show their IDs to Uncle Jack's gang?

Tags: breaking-bad

When Jack and his crew comes to desert and pull their guns at Hank And Gomie, Hank says we are police, and Jack asks multiple times to show some ID so that they won't fire. But Hank and Gomie never showed their badge?

Only reason I could think of is that letting know that they are with DEA could rather have more negative effects on the situation than positive as the Nazis already looked like drug dealers. Is that it? Or would the Nazis have gone away after seeing their ID as killing DEA agents without any reason is not a smart move.

Comment: Do you really think Jack would stop firing if Hank or Gomes had produced some ID?  Do you think it might be possible that Jack might be taking advantage of law abiding police, by asking them to produce ID to distract them? I think Hank and Gomez probably realized that this was a ploy to distract them.

Comment: Like Hank said: “It doesn’t take a genius to realize he’s already made his decision, Walt.” Hank knew he was done the minute he was staring down the barrel of Jack’s gun.

Comment: Sounds like something that could be an answer @MissouriSpartan .... I couldn't quite remember the details of the scene, but a quote showing Hanks mindset is good enough.

Comment: Hank said (to Walt) something like "You're the smartest guy I ever met and yet you're too stupid to see he [Jack] made up his mind 10 minutes ago" (his mind being to kill Hank). Brilliant scenes, but imo these "10 minutes" start when Jack approaches Hank who is severely injured (after the shooting). Anyway,  I agree with @iandotkelly, if Hank and Gomez had "opened themselves" and shown their IDs, they would have been either disarmed or simply and easily killed.